# Highcharts export to svg

Tags: javascript, macos, phantomjs, highcharts

Based upon this [tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts), I am successfully running the following (simplified) example :

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile options1.json -outfile chart1.png -width 300 -constr Chart
```

I can change the outputfile extension to `.jpg` or `.pdf` and get the expected output but when I change it to `.svg` the `chart1.svg` file that is successfully created is empty.

From `highcharts-convert.js`, here are the instructions which fails at writing that file :

```
fs = require('fs');
...
svgFile = fs.open(output, "w");
svgFile.write(svg);
```

I checked `console.log(svg)` and `svg`is not empty, so the guilty one is `svgFile.write(svg);` but why?

I am running Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in Highcharts, after writing to the stream, stream should be closed, so this should look this way:

```
                if (!runsAsServer) {
                    // write the file
                    svgFile = fs.open(output, "w");
                    svgFile.write(svg);
                    svgFile.close(); //add this line
                    exit(output);
                } else {
                    // return the svg as a string
                    exit(svg);
                }
```

Reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1869

Comment: Thanks a lot Pawel! What is strange is (after that) I have compiled that code and it is running perfectly on Tomcat.